# SQL join within each group

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have Table1(A, B, C), and Table2(B)

```
Table1:
A    |    B    |    C
------------------------
a1        b1        c1
a1        b2        c2 
a2        b1        c3
```

```
Table2:
B   
--
b1     
b2       
b3       
b4
```

The result I want:

```
A   |   B   |   C
-------------------
a1      b1      c1
a1      b2      c2
a1      b3    [some default value]
a1      b4    [some default value]
a2      b1      c3
a2      b2    [some default value]
a2      b3    [some default value]
a2      b4    [some default value]
```

How can I do this?

Essentially I need a way to right outer join table1 with table2, but "group by" column A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result by `CROSS JOIN`ing the distinct values of `A` from `Table1` with the values of `B` from `Table2` and then `LEFT JOIN`ing to `Table1` again to get the corresponding `C` values, using `COALESCE` to supply a default value where there is no matching `C` value:

```
SELECT t1.A, t2.B, COALESCE(t3.C, 'c0') AS C
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT A
      FROM Table1) t1
CROSS JOIN Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t3 ON t3.A = t1.A AND t3.B = t2.B
```

Output:

```
a   b   c
a1  b1  c1
a1  b2  c2
a1  b3  c0
a1  b4  c0
a2  b1  c3
a2  b3  c0
a2  b2  c0
a2  b4  c0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w6HjyQ8RWTFESLYSaY1x6j/0)